# Get field names in Formula Language

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-formula

I'm *almost* certain there's a way in the Notes Formula language to get the names of items ("fields") on a document, but I can't remember it, and there's no cross-reference from NotesDocument.Items in the documentation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay, I thought of a place where I used this, and dug it up.  It's `@DocFields`.   I had been trying `@DocItems`, `@GetItems`, etc.

Comment: It's interesting that not only do many developers not know the actual meaning of *field* and confuse it with *item* (*fields* are on forms and *items* are on documents), but also whoever was designing/extending the Formula Language at the time this was added either didn't know the difference or was catering to the developers who don't know the difference.  I would have expected the language itself to use the correct term, just as LotusScript used the correct term.